# Hosting a dynamic RSS feed

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm a newbie to GAE and am trying to work out how to host an RSS feed based on data stored on the service. 
So far I can't work out an obvious way to do it having read through the docs.
Can anyone give me some pointers as to what API I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an API? You can query for updated data using the normal query classes, and output the feed using the standard Python XML tools like ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't any different to serving a dynamic HTML page. Do it exactly the same way you would serve up an HTML template, but generate RSS or Atom instead of HTML.

Comment: I see! For some reason I assumed you could only serve web pages with it unless you used some special API.

Comment: @BenBtg No, App Engine doesn't care what mimetype you serve up, or what the body of the response consists of.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a quick solution is [gae-rest](https://github.com/fczuardi/gae-rest) but it is as old as 2008. You may find my solution helpful that renders my data to a GeoRSS template, so here's my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">

<title>{{host}}</title>
<link href="http://{{host}}" rel="self"/>
<id>http://{{host}}/</id>
<updated>2011-09-17T08:14:49.875423Z</updated>
<generator uri="http://{{host}}/">{{host}}</generator>

{% for ad in ads %}

<entry>

<title><![CDATA[{{ad.title}}]]></title>
<link href="http://{{host}}/vi/{{ad.key.id}}"/>
<id>http://{{host}}/vi/{{ad.key.id}}</id>
<updated>{{ad.modified.isoformat}}Z</updated>
<author><name>{{ad.title|escape}}</name></author>
<georss:point>{{ad.geopt.lon|floatformat:2}},{{ad.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}</georss:point>
<published>{{ad.added}}</published>
<summary type="xhtml"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">{{ad.text|escape}}</div>
</summary>

</entry>

{% endfor %}

</feed>
```

handler:

```
class GeoRSS(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        start = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=60)
        count = (int(self.request.get('count'
                 )) if not self.request.get('count') == '' else 1000)
    try:
        ads = memcache.get('ads')
    except KeyError:
        ads = Ad.all().filter('modified >',
                            start).filter('published =',
                True).order('-modified').fetch(count)
    memcache.set('ads', ads)
        template_values = {'ads': ads, 'request': self.request,
                           'host': os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST',
                           os.environ['SERVER_NAME'])}
        dispatch = 'templates/georss.html'
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
        output = template.render(path, template_values)
        self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=%s" % 86400
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/rss+xml'
        self.response.out.write(output)
```